# Google assistant conversation with Android app

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am developing an app which needs Google Assistant(GA) to interact with my app installed in Android phone. With GA Actions, I can open my app or I can show some data on GA using slices. That works fine. I am looking for GA conversational behaviour which is very similar to GA conversation with Clock or Reminder apps in Android phone.

For Eg:-
Me: Hey Google, Set Reminder for tomorrow
GA: Alright, tomorrow at what time?
Me: 10 am
GA: Sure, tomorrow at 10:00 AM. What's the reminder?
and so on..

As per [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview), Conversational flow works with Dialog flow/ ActionsSdk which communicates with our server backend and display's the result.

I looked deeply in Dialog flow & ActionsSdk but I didn't found any way to directly interact with my app for conversation.
Can anyone please help me how I can I make GA to interact with my installed app instead of server backend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe your app has to interact with your backend server as the conversation/dialogflow is with the backend server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Morrison. Yes the app has to interact with backend server. But looking for GA to interact with app with conversation flow.

Comment: In general purposes you can't get assistant to open your app. It's for specific things like fitness that App Actions works, and for alarms/timers there are other specific intents to implement in your app.